# How to Save Current date and time values in Document Directory?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, date

[image]

As my above screen shot show that I want to show Two values in Each cell of Tableview. I can do it if I have the data which I want to show in these labels of Cell in the same Class,but problem for me is I am try to getting both these labels from other view or other class using (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) so for I got success to show one value as my screenshot show ,but the other part which consist of current data and time Display is still problem for me.Now here is my code which i try so for.

```
NSString *fina = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mySongname];
NSArray  *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir  = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyRecordings"];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:soundFilePath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:soundFilePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    soundFilePath = [soundFilePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fina];
    recordedTmpFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile settings:recordSetting error:&error];
    [recorder setDelegate:self];
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    [recorder record];
    [recordSetting release];
```

The above part of Code works fine it display the value in Tableview Cell that my screenshow.Now in same function I am try to getting the data to show it in red part which is my UILabel in Tableview Cell using Below Code.

```
 NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd:MMM:YY_hh:mm:ss a"];
 NSString *file= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
 NSLog(@"myfinaldate:%@",file);
```

Now i want to save this date value in same directory which i use above and to show it red parts of UITableview .
Now here is my Code where i use this Tableview and getting these document directory value.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyRecordings"];
directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:documentPath];
      NSLog(@"file found %i",[directoryContent count]);
[directoryContent retain];
[self.tableView reloadData];
  }

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
static NSInteger StateTag = 1;
static NSInteger CapitalTag = 2;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    UILabel *capitalLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2, 80, 20)];
    //capitalLabel.text=@"mydata";
    capitalLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    capitalLabel.tag = CapitalTag;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:capitalLabel];
    [capitalLabel release];

    UILabel *stateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 22, 310, 20)];
    stateLabel.tag = StateTag;
    [stateLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    stateLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:stateLabel];
    [stateLabel release];

}
UILabel * stateLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:StateTag];
//UILabel * capitalLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:CapitalTag];

stateLabel.text = [directoryContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//capitalLabel.text = [directoryContent1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return cell;
 }
```

Now I am trying to summarize the problem.
How we can save the date and time value in same directory and then how to show here in Red part of UITableview Cell?
capitalLabel is my Redpart of Cell to show date and time which is problem.
stateLabel all ready show the values. so no problem with this label. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do this....

you can set `NSCachesDirectory` to `NSDocumentDirectory`

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:yourComponent];
//    NSLog(@"Path : %@",writableDBPath);

NSMutableDictionary *plistArr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:writableDBPath];
```

Comment: After saving value then how we can fetch it.